# MS Access query to pull records between date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Microsoft Query to pull data from an Access database.  I'm trying to pull data between tomorrow at 01:00:00 and the following morning at 00:00:00.  I've tried everything from

```
WHERE (acct_data.Date Between DATEADD(DAY,1, DateADD(HOUR,1, GETDATE())) And DATEADD(DAY,2, GETDATE())))
```

to

```
WHERE (acct_data.Date Between DATEADD(DAY,1, DateADD(HOUR,1, GETDATE())) And DATEADD(DAY,2, GETDATE())))
```

and everything(except the correct code)in between.  Does anyone know the correct syntax to get data from tomorrow at 1AM to midnight?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Excel MS Query to pull data from Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011983/using-excel-ms-query-to-pull-data-from-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the MS Access syntax:

```
WHERE acct_data.Date >= dateadd("h", 25, now()) And 
      acct_data.Date < dateadd("d", 2, now())
```

Comment: Thank you for your response   I'm getting a "Too few parameters.  Expected 2." alert.   I got that same message with some of my other attempts.

Comment: I just noticed my title has been edited. I'm actually using Excel to pull data from Access using Microsoft Query. I don't own the Access database, but I have permission to query a table with Excel.

Comment: Gordon, it is not _hour_ and _day_ but _h_ and _d_ only.

Comment: Also, the `BETWEEN`operator as OP originally used can work here as well. In fact, it is recommended per the MSDN doc's for [Query Performance Tips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942824(v=office.12).aspx#odc_ac2007_ta_PerformanceTipsToSpeedUpYourAccessDB_QueryPerformanceTips) as engine evaluates condition once not twice, though range is inclusive of both start/end points.

Comment: @Parfait . . . As a general rule, avoid using `between` with date/time columns.  Semantic correctness and maintainability are also important.  A good explanation is provided by Aaron Bertrand https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common (most of the idea apply to databases other than SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the replies everyone.   I should have asked a mod to get rid of this thread.   I restated my problem in another thread.  I wasn't clear in the title on this thread, and the title was changed.   I though this thread wouldn't get any more attention when I marked an accepted answer(since Gordon's answer was for Access syntax).   I realize now that MS Query does use Access syntax(I originally thought that, but my queries keep getting error messages)  I'll try your suggestion again, Gordon(with "d" and "h").   I thought I tried the same already, but I must not have.