# Using Excel MS Query to pull data from Access

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I'm using Microsoft Query in Excel to pull data from an Access database.   I don't own the Access database, but I have permission to query its tables and queries using my Excel spreadsheet.   I'm trying to pull data between tomorrow at 01:00:00 and the following morning at 00:00:00.  I've tried everything from

```
WHERE (acct_data.Date Between DATEADD(DAY,1, DateADD(HOUR,1, GETDATE())) And DATEADD(DAY,2, GETDATE())))
```

to

```
WHERE (acct_data.Date Between DATEADD(DAY,1, DateADD(HOUR,1, GETDATE())) And DATEADD(DAY,2, GETDATE())))
```

and everything(except the correct code)in between.  Does anyone know the correct syntax to get data from tomorrow at 1AM to midnight?

Comment: You might want to try changing `GetDate()` to `DATE()`. Furthermore, I am thinking that `acct_date` is the column and not the table. Then you should skip appending `.Date` to it. If Date is the actual column name then this might be a problem. Other than that it should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query for retreiving records that fall on the last day of the month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830458/sql-query-for-retreiving-records-that-fall-on-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Comment: Why did you ask exact [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011448/ms-access-query-to-pull-records-between-date) nearly verbatim with an already accepted answer hours ago? MS Query uses same exact engine as MS Access (i.e., Jet/ACE). So SQL dialect would be the same.

Comment: Parfait, I probably should have contacted a mod about my other question.   I wasn't clear in stating my problem in my other question, and the title of the thread was changed.  It appeared that I wanted to make the query in access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved.

```
WHERE ((([Acct_data]. [Date] Between Date() + 1.04166 And Date() + 2
```

It works now.   I literally copied and pasted from a notepad file that I saved it in yesterday.   I tried it one more time to see what error message that I was getting.  Not sure why I received no error today.   I think I was getting a "parameter expected" message.   I must have had something wrong somewhere else in the process.

Thanks for your help everyone.   Ryguy72, if you wouldn't have posted that link, I would have give up that route.  I decided to give it another go.